# az update service-endpoints using variable

Tags: azure, service, command-line-interface, endpoint

I'm trying to add multiple Service-Endpoints to subnets using the update command, and having a variable to represent the SE's

When it runs, it fails with and error saying that the array is using an invalid service name.

When running the command without a variable for the SE's, it runs with out any problem.

```
$SE = "Microsoft.KeyVault Microsoft.Storage"

az network vnet subnet update --service-endpoints $SE --resource-group MyRg1 --vnet-name MyVnet --name MySnet

## Used to display the varaible format
Write-host "az network vnet subnet update --service-endpoints $SE --resource-group MyRg1 --vnet-name MyVnet --name MySnet"
```

Using a loop, and adding each SE is not a good option, as the update cmd is idempotent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with how powershell handles variables; the $SE that you pass in is a single positional parameter, whereas the az client parses them as being distinct.
This is a common problem with powershell. For example, consider an application that prints the command line arguments:

```
> $SE = "my args"
> MyExe.exe $SE something else
```

The output would be:

```
arg0: MyExe.exe
arg1: my args
arg2: something
arg3: else
```

To correct this, you need to instruct powershell to split the string into an array, which (when it builds a commandline for `az`) gets split into multiple args:

```
az network vnet subnet update --service-endpoints $($SE -split ' ') --resource-group MyRg1 --vnet-name MyVnet --name MySnet
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameter `--service-endpoints` accepts space-separated list of services.

The error is because you are not supplying a space-separated list. Instead you are providing a simple string with spaces in it.

```
az network vnet subnet update --service-endpoints Microsoft.KeyVault Microsoft.Storage
```

The above command should resolve your issue.

**UPDATE :**

I tried @KommandanKeen's approach. I was not able to get it working. You could give it a shot see whether it is working for you.

Alternatively, I came up with a workaround  :

By making use of the Invoke Expression - Invoke-Expression evaluates a string as a command.

```
Invoke-Expression "az network vnet subnet update --service-endpoints $SE --resource-group MyRg1 --vnet-name MyVnet --name MySnet"
```

In this case the $SE is expanded and the command string is formulated.

```
 az network vnet subnet update --service-endpoints Microsoft.KeyVault Microsoft.Storage......
```

Now, the command string is evaluated as an expression.

Comment: It's not resolve, if I want to use a variable as the space-separated list of services.

Comment: The command itself did not work or are you looking for a way to dynamically generate the service endpoints ?

Comment: The command you specified would work at any time. The issue is when using a variable with the values for the service-endpoints. Ex.

az network vnet subnet update --service-endpoints **$SE** --resource-group MyRg1 --vnet-name MyVnet --name MySnet

Comment: I really appreciate your effort, KommandanKeen's approach is working in my script. A big thanks for your time :)